# strange issue logging in remotely to my 20.04 server via SSH?

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh, password

I found an SSH tutorial for 20.04, followed it, and successfully created an SSH key pair and stored it on my server, and did a bunch of other things, etc. Exactly as it showed. Everything seemed to work, except the final step, which is to sign in via ssh. I connected to my server via Kitty (a spin-off of Putty), got to the logon prompt, and tried "ssh root@myIP" but it asked for a password.  I used my normal one, and it logs in.  But isn't it supposed to just instantly logon, skipping the password? Or is there another step?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You *cannot* SSH into the `root` account. You SSH in with a proper user account and, if you need to do things as the admin, you use `sudo` or `su` 

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you create your SSH key pair? Can you provide the link to the tutorial you followed? I assume your client is a Windows box since you're using Kitty.

The general instructions to connect to a server via SSH with a private/public key pair via Kitty are as follows:

- Use Putty KeyGen to create the private/public key pair
- Copy your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server
- Provide the path to the private key within Kitty under `SSH->Auth`

Here are a couple tutorials that might help:

[KiTTY – The Pretty Terminal Emulator](https://aufather.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/kitty-the-pretty-terminal-emulator/)

[Using SSH Keys with PuTTY](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/putty-ssh-keys/)

Comment: Sure: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-20-04  I think I see the issue as @matigo said, I apparently can't use root with SSH.  Okay, I'll check out those links and see about making a new user.  I'm using a remote server that I access via console in Kitty. Thanks!

Comment: @zoldos Yeah, you should just login as a regular user, and the SSH public key should be copied to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for this specific user.